# how do i search lastNames saved in my arraylist in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

```
public void searchLastName(String lastName)
{
    int size = list.size();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if(list.get(i).getLastName().equals(lastName))
            System.out.print(lastName+ " is located at " +i);
        else
            System.out.println("Cant find at loc:" +i);

    }
}
```

is there any problem with this code?? i cant search the lastName.. please help me guys

this is from class Person

`public String getLastName()
{
return lastName;
}`

Comment: Your code looks fine, assuming that `list` is a `List<String>`, and `lastName` is a `String`. What output/error are you getting?

Comment: @WChargin it can't be a String List, it looks like a custom Object list. Unless String now has a `getLastName()` method.

Comment: its a custom object.. List<Person> its like a address im doing here... and i want to search  the last name.. so thats it..

Comment: @A--C: of course; my apologies. @applegate: What is this code doing that you don't want it to? Could you post the implementation of `getLastName()`, or, better yet, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: this is from class Person

public String getLastName(){return lastName;}

Comment: Just an aside, you should be using an `Iterator` instead of `List.get(int index)` if you're going for efficient code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your code is that it will print out the "Can't find..." message for all locations that do not match, even if some locations do match. Perhaps that's what you want. However, if you want one location where `lastName` is found, you can do something like this:

```
int found = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < size && found == -1; ++i) {
    if (list.get(i).getLastName().equals(lastName)) {
        found = i;
    }
}
if (found >= 0) {
    System.out.print(lastName+ " is located at " + found);
} else {
    System.out.println("Cant find " + lastName);
}
```

If you want *all* locations where it is found, you can do this:

```
List<Integer> found = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (list.get(i).getLastName().equals(lastName)) {
        found.add(i);
    }
}
if (found.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Cant find " + lastName);
} else {
    System.out.print(lastName+ " is located at " + found.toString());
}
```

Comment: still not working >_< or should i say.. still cant find the lastName >_<

Comment: You'll need to post the code for `getLastName()` and whatever method calls `searchLastName(String lastname)`; if those work as one would expect, this answer should fix your problem.

Comment: @G.Bach yea i know.. i can read codes lol.. but still.. why the hell it doesnt work >_<

Comment: @applegate - If it's still not working, perhaps the problem is that one of the strings (`lastName` or the name stored in the `Person` object) has leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @TedHopp i trailed it.. and it somehow like this... class ExtPerson IS-A class Person... thanks for your help dude! i really appreciate fast and reliable help.. oh btw. im noob so that's why im asking here. >_< sorry for disturbing you all :|